# angualrjs ng-repeat data-toggle issue

Tags: angularjs

I have a below code :`

```
<DIV class="panel-group" ng-repeat="ent in EntitlementList | unique:'attributename'">
        <DIV   class="panel panel-default">
            <div style="height: 40px; margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 2%; margin-top: 1%">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="getEntitlement(ent.attributename)"
                    data-target="#collapse{{$index}}"> {{ent.attributename}}</a>
            </div>
            <DIV id="collapse{{$index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div ng-repeat="ep in EndpointList"
                        <div style="height: 20px; margin-left: 2%; margin-top: 1%;">{{ep.endpointname}}</div>
                </div>
            </DIV>
        </DIV>
</DIV>
```

`    say I have 3 links,when i expand the each link after collapsing the previous one, It is working fine. But the problem i am facing is,  if i expand the second link without collapsing the first one, the value of the second link is overriding the value of the first link.
    Please help me to resolve this issue.
    Java script file has the following function:

```
$scope.getEntitlement = function(selecteEntitlement)
 {
            var finalList=[];
    $scope.EndpointList="";
    $scope.entitlementInfo.forEach(function(entitlement) 
    {
    if(entitlement.attributename == selecteEntitlement)
        {
             finalList.push({endpointname: entitlement.endpointname
                 });
     }
       });
            $scope.EndpointList = finalList;
 };
```

Comment: You should show what's inside of EntitlementList, or make a plunker to demonstrate your problem. It would help people to see your problem quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is using the same variable $scope.EndpointList for every expandable click. The solution is, you have create separate EndpointList for each ent (element from EntitlementList), then you could use

```
ng-repeat="ep in ent.EndpointList"
```